# Windows 7: Slide-window-back-on-screen feature

Tags: windows-7, windows

On my laptop I use at work, whenever you drag a window so that a portion of it is off-screen, and then move the mouse towards the direction it is cut off in, it will begin to proportionately slide the window back onto the screen until it is entirely in view. What this does is effectively increase the amount of available "space" for moving and organizing application windows to, since it dramatically reduces the time it takes to make a particular window fully visible again, or e.g. if you reposition something sloppily you can quite easily adjust it to at least see the whole window.

Now I can't tell what actually is responsible for implementing this awesome little feature, but I have started to get used to it, and my Windows 7 Ultimate installation at home does not behave like this.

So I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this and if they know more about what's going on here.

In my Googling I have only found various directions for doing awful things like getting a window's context menu and choosing `Move` or something ridiculous like that. No, this is some sort of mysterious functionality that directly causes the window to slide back onto the screen by simply moving the mouse towards the cut-off portion of a window. Not a single click is needed.

If I get a lot of "What? Never seen that!" comments I will make a screen capture on the machine (at home right now).

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It's some kind of Thinkpad (or Synaptics touchpad) specific feature. There's a chance if you can force it to be installed somehow we can gain this functionality on a regular windows install.

http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/230610-how-do-i-turn-off-feature-auto-moves-windows-screen.html